# How to collect information about bytecode instructions before 'getfield' and 'putfield'?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I work with the byte-buddy-maven plugin. I need to walk through constructors and method code and collect information about bytecode instruction before 'getfield' and 'putfield' instructions. How I can do this?
I know about MemberSubstitution, but I need to call static methods of utility class with the field name.
Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.mylib;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.MemberSubstitution;
import net.bytebuddy.build.BuildLogger;
import net.bytebuddy.build.Plugin;
import net.bytebuddy.description.ByteCodeElement;
import net.bytebuddy.description.TypeVariableSource;
import net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription.Generic.Visitor;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeList;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.ClassFileLocator;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.StackManipulation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.constant.JavaConstantValue;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.MethodInvocation;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;
import net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.JavaConstant;

/**
 *
 * @author makarov
 */
public class ByteBuddyPlugin implements Plugin {

    private final BuildLogger logger;

    public ByteBuddyPlugin(BuildLogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescription target) {
        return target.getDeclaredAnnotations()
                .isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public DynamicType.Builder<?> apply(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassFileLocator classFileLocator) {
        try {
            Method setValueMethod = ObjectDB.class.getMethod("setValue", Object.class, String.class, Object.class); // args, first - value from aload_0, second - field name, third - value (in byte byte some instruction)
            Method getValueMethod = ObjectDB.class.getMethod("getValue", Object.class, String.class); // args: 1 - value from aload_0, 2 - field name
            
            logger.info(String.format("applying for %s", typeDescription.getSimpleName()));
            return builder.visit(
                    MemberSubstitution.strict()
                            .field(ElementMatchers.declaresAnnotation(ElementMatchers.annotationType(Field.class)))
                            .onWrite()
                            .replaceWith(new MemberSubstitution.Substitution.Factory() {
                                
                                @Override
                                public MemberSubstitution.Substitution make(TypeDescription instrumentedType, MethodDescription instrumentedMethod, TypePool typePool) {
                                    logger.info(String.format("substitution writer in method %s", instrumentedMethod));
                                    
                                    return new MemberSubstitution.Substitution() {
                                        
                                        @Override
                                        public StackManipulation resolve(TypeDescription targetType, ByteCodeElement target, TypeList.Generic parameters, TypeDescription.Generic result, int freeOffset) {
                                            logger.info(String.format("resolve targetType %s, target %s, parameters %s, result %s, freeOffset %s", targetType, target, parameters, result, freeOffset));
                                            
                                            String fieldName = target.getDeclaredAnnotations()
                                                    .ofType(Field.class)
                                                    .load()
                                                    .value();
                                            
                                            logger.info(String.format("fieldName: %s", fieldName));
                                            
                                            // Here is my question... I need to get existing instruction that pushes assigning value to stack for 'putfield' (third argument of 'setValueMethod')

                                            return new StackManipulation.Compound(
                                                    new JavaConstantValue(JavaConstant.Simple.ofLoaded(fieldName)),
                                                    ... //  existing instruction,
                                                    MethodInvocation.invoke(new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(setValueMethod))
                                            );
                                        }
                                    };
                                }
                            }).on(ElementMatchers.any())
            );
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("closing"));
        /* do nothing */
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do some transformations" and "analyze" aren't very specific. Stack Overflow isn't really suited for giving tutorials, you should ask a specific question that has a definite answer. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I still don't understand what is it that you have an issue with?

Comment: I'll clarify my question now

Comment: I’m not sure whether ByteBuddy still makes the task easier, compared to directly using ASM for this specific task. Besides that, why are you writing constructs like `String.format("fieldName: %s", fieldName)` instead of a simple `"fieldName: " + fieldName`?

Comment: This is for uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to act based on specific byte code instructions, Byte Buddy exposes ASM for this exact purpose. The `MemberSubstitution` is rather meant for situations where you want to "replace calls to method A with calls to method B" or "instead of reading field C, call method D".

Byte Buddy is stateless, ASM is stateful. In your case, you want to make a change based on a previous state and ASM is the choice for this. You can still use Byte Buddy for the Maven plugin and method matching, but use a `MethodVisitor` which you can register via a `AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods`.